# Swift Disable UIGestures for subviews

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, gmsmapview

I'm having some troubles with uigestures on subviews.

I have a MapView on a UIViewController and a subview with a tableView which is hidden.

So when I run the app, I can't use gestures on the MapView (scroll, zoom, etc) because the tableView is blocking them.

The table view is loaded from a Xib file, im using it to display google predictions for directions. So it is hidden and only showed when a uitext field change to show the predictions and pick one.

What can I do to disable the gestures on the tableview when it is hidden and enable them again when the tableview is shown?

Thanks!

Comment: Hidden views don't participate in event dispatch. Are you sure the subview and the table view are hidden?

Comment: the table view is loaded from a Xib file, im using it to display google predictions for directions. So it is hidden and only showed when a uitext field change to show the predictions and pick one.